# Extending models in Laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationship

In my application I have a User (duh)

```
class User {

    public function teams()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Team::class, 'team_user', 'user_id')->wherePivot('confirmed', '!=', null);
    }
}
```

Im trying to make a model that extends the `User`, like so

```
class Teamleader extends User
{
    protected $table = 'users';

    public static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::addGlobalScope(new TeamleaderScope);
    }
}
```

The idea is that a team leader is a user that has the `isLeader` boolean in the `team_user` pivot table set to true. In my `TeamleaderScope` I've 
tried something like

```
class TeamleaderScope implements Scope
{
    public function apply(Builder $builder, Model $model)
    {
        $model->teams()->wherePivot('isLeader', true);
    }
}
```

but that seems to be wrong, cause `Teamleader::all(`) just returns all the users. I've never tried extending a model like this, but it should be possible, right? Can anyone help me in the right direction?

Comment: Ramin offers guidance below that conforms to the OOP principle of favoring composition over inheritance, which is a good idea here. I have gone down this road using both inheritance and traits, and just want to offer the opinion it is frequently more trouble than it's worth. A situation where I have found model inheritance useful is connecting to legacy databases where there are multiple very different entities in the same table, but that doesn't look like the case here.

Comment: Maybe try this in your scope's `apply()` method: ```$builder->whereHas('team_user', function ($query) {
    $query->wherePivot('isLeader', true);
});```

Answer (score 2):

for reuse the common method and etc in the two class in PHP, you can use the `trait`.
in your case, create a php file in next to the rest of the models and I named it `CommonTrait.php` and inside it must like below:

```
<?php

namespace App;


trait CommonTrait
{
    public function commonMethodOne()
    {
        // anything
    }

    public function commonMethodTwo()
    {
        // anything
    }

    // for get leaders.
    public function scopeLeaders()
    {
        return $this->teams()->wherePivot('isLeader', true);
    }

    public function scopeSearchLeaders($query, $keyword)
    {
         return $query->where('name', $keyword)->wherePivot('isLeader', true);
    }


}
```

so now you use `trait` anywhere that you want.

for example, use it in the `User.php`:

```
<?php

namespace App;

class User
{
    use CommonTrait;
}
```

so, now all method or variable in `CommonTrait.php` accessible in the `User.php` and you capable using the those in the `User.php` and you can use it in the `Teamleader.php` and using all method it in the `Teamleader.php`.
for example, now if you want to get users that are team leaders, you can try followings code:

```
$leaders = User::Leaders();
$resultSearch = User::SearchLeaders("Gard Mikael");
```

I hope be useful

Comment: Thank you for replying. I guess I can use Traits. But shouldn't there be some sort of restrictions. If Teamleader is just a model that refers to the same users table, I would still be able to say Teameleader::find(1), even though the user with the id of 1 not necessarily is a teamleader. Im not really sure in which scenario this will become a problem, but if the logic should be correct Teamleaders would only be a subset of Users, right? Anyway, thanks

Comment: @GardMikaelFjeldavli right, I edited my answers, You can will defines scopes that related with team leaders and using those methods with `User::`